# r deSolve - plotting time evolution pde

Tags: r, surface, pde

suppose that we have a pde that describes the evolution of a variable y(t,x) over time t and space x, and I would like to plot its evolution on a three dimensional diagram (t,x,y). With deSolve I can solve the pde, but I have no idea about how to obtain this kind of diagram.

The example in the deSolve package instruction is the following, where y is aphids, t=0,...,200 and x=1,...,60:

```
library(deSolve)

Aphid <- function(t, APHIDS, parameters) {
deltax <- c (0.5, rep(1, numboxes - 1), 0.5)
Flux <- -D * diff(c(0, APHIDS, 0)) / deltax
dAPHIDS <- -diff(Flux) / delx + APHIDS * r
list(dAPHIDS )
}

D <- 0.3 # m2/day diffusion rate
r <- 0.01 # /day net growth rate
delx <- 1 # m thickness of boxes
numboxes <- 60
Distance <- seq(from = 0.5, by = delx, length.out = numboxes)

APHIDS <- rep(0, times = numboxes)
APHIDS[30:31] <- 1
state <- c(APHIDS = APHIDS) # initialise state variables

times <-seq(0, 200, by = 1)
out <- ode.1D(state, times, Aphid, parms = 0, nspec = 1, names = "Aphid")
```

"out" produces a matrix containing all the data that we need, t, y(x1), y(x2), ... y(x60). How can I produce a surface plot to show the evolution and variability of y in (t,x)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ways change a bit depending on using package. But you can do it with little cost because `out[,-1]` is an ideal matrix form to draw surface. I showed two examples using `rgl` and `plot3D` package.

```
out2 <- out[,-1]
AphID  <- 1:ncol(out2)

library(rgl)
persp3d(times, AphID, out2, col="gray50", zlab="y")
 # If you want to change color with value of Z-axis
 # persp3d(times, AphID, out2, zlab="y", col=topo.colors(256)[cut(c(out2), 256)])

library(plot3D)
mat <- mesh(times, AphID)
surf3D(mat$x, mat$y, out2, bty="f", ticktype="detailed", xlab="times", ylab="AphID", zlab="y")
```

[image]